# How to protect spammers to apache?

Tags: virtualhost, apache

I have the following for `www.domain.com` and `login.domain.com`. But spammers forward there site to `login.domain.com` and it works. How can I block them?

Ex: `http://spammerexmaple.sex.com` opens `http://login.domain.com` (I want to block this)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName login.domain.com
 ServerAlias login.domain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/com/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/com/public>
        #AddDefaultCharset utf-8
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.domain.com
 ServerAlias domain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/www/public>
    # Compress output
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        #AddDefaultCharset utf-8
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Follow up:**

Spammers forward `www.spammer.com` to `login.domain.com` or `www.spammer.sex.com` anything someone can forward to `login.domain.com` and it works.

How can I block this?

```
[root@d dd.dd.com]# httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          d (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:81)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server dummy.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1028)
         port 80 namevhost dummy.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1028)
         port 80 namevhost dd.dd.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1039)
         port 80 namevhost aa.aa.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1058)
Syntax OK





<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName dummy.com
 DocumentRoot /tmp
 <Directory /tmp>
        deny from all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName dd.dd.com
 #ServerAlias dd.dd.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dd.dd.com/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/dd.dd.com/public>
        #AddDefaultCharset utf-8
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName aa.aa.com
 ServerAlias aa.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/aa.aa.com/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/aa.aa.com/public>
    # Compress output
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        #AddDefaultCharset utf-8
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Comment: Suggest that this is probably better on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action 1: Iptables are best + Physical routers such as Cisco Pix or other routers and making black lists + checking the incoming source ip with black listed ip networks, and suspend there access to our network.

Action 2: Putting some moderators, who screen  the incoming traffic and bounce  them as soon as possible and mark them spammer, and also report those to other networks

Action 3: god bless us, and hope we get more informations.. its a unlimited game, never ends.

Hope  it help others at-least to know possibilities.